# How to add/restore the value of process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ReactJs in an application and I need to add process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL.

I want to use .env variables in my react application.

I created an app using (create-react-app template)

Initially It was working till for one day and after that I am not sure what happened with the application. Now `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` is returning undefined.

Please see my tried code

```
import { take, fork, cancel, call, put, cancelled } from 'redux-saga/effects';

// We'll use this function to redirect to different routes based on cases
import history from '../../history';
// Helper for api errors
import { handleApiErrors } from '../../lib/api-errors';
//import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
// Our login constants
import {
  LOGIN_REQUESTING,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_ERROR,
} from '../../constants/login'

// So that we can modify our Client piece of state
import {
  setClient,
  unsetClient,
} from '../../actions/client'

import {
  CLIENT_UNSET,
} from '../../constants/client'

const loginUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/Clients/login`

function loginApi (email, password) {
  debugger;
  return fetch(loginUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  })
    .then(handleApiErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => json)
    .catch((error) => { throw error })
}

function* logout () {
  // dispatches the CLIENT_UNSET action
  yield put(unsetClient())

  // remove our token
  localStorage.removeItem('token')

  // redirect to the /login screen
  history.push('/login')
}

function* loginFlow (email, password) {
  let token
  try {
    // try to call to our loginApi() function.  Redux Saga
    // will pause here until we either are successful or
    // receive an error
    token = yield call(loginApi, email, password)

    // inform Redux to set our client token, this is non blocking so...
    yield put(setClient(token))

    // .. also inform redux that our login was successful
    yield put({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS })

    // set a stringified version of our token to localstorage on our domain
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token))

    // redirect them to WIDGETS!
    history.push('/widgets')
  } catch (error) {
    // error? send it to redux
    yield put({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, error })
  } finally {
    // No matter what, if our `forked` `task` was cancelled
    // we will then just redirect them to login
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      history.push('/login')
    }
  }

  // return the token for health and wealth
  return token
}

// Our watcher (saga).  It will watch for many things.
function* loginWatcher () {
  // Generators halt execution until their next step is ready/occurring
  // So it's not like this loop is firing in the background 1000/sec
  // Instead, it says, "okay, true === true", and hits the first step...
  while (true) {
    //
    // ... and in this first it sees a yield statement with `take` which
    // pauses the loop.  It will sit here and WAIT for this action.
    //
    // yield take(ACTION) just says, when our generator sees the ACTION
    // it will pull from that ACTION's payload that we send up, its
    // email and password.  ONLY when this happens will the loop move
    // forward...
    const { email, password } = yield take(LOGIN_REQUESTING)

    // ... and pass the email and password to our loginFlow() function.
    // The fork() method spins up another "process" that will deal with
    // handling the loginFlow's execution in the background!
    // Think, "fork another process".
    //
    // It also passes back to us, a reference to this forked task
    // which is stored in our const task here.  We can use this to manage
    // the task.
    //
    // However, fork() does not block our loop.  It's in the background
    // therefore as soon as our loop executes this it mores forward...
    const task = yield fork(loginFlow, email, password)

    // ... and begins looking for either CLIENT_UNSET or LOGIN_ERROR!
    // That's right, it gets to here and stops and begins watching
    // for these tasks only.  Why would it watch for login any more?
    // During the life cycle of this generator, the user will login once
    // and all we need to watch for is either logging out, or a login
    // error.  The moment it does grab either of these though it will
    // once again move forward...
    const action = yield take([CLIENT_UNSET, LOGIN_ERROR])

    // ... if, for whatever reason, we decide to logout during this
    // cancel the current action.  i.e. the user is being logged
    // in, they get impatient and start hammering the logout button.
    // this would result in the above statement seeing the CLIENT_UNSET
    // action, and down here, knowing that we should cancel the
    // forked `task` that was trying to log them in.  It will do so
    // and move forward...
    if (action.type === CLIENT_UNSET) yield cancel(task)

    // ... finally we'll just log them out.  This will unset the client
    // access token ... -> follow this back up to the top of the while loop
    yield call(logout)
  }
}

export default loginWatcher
```

What should I do in my code?

I've grabbed the example code from here: https://github.com/jcolemorrison/redux-sagas-authentication-app

```
Application built with
{
  "react": "16.13.0", 
  "react-dom": "^16.13.0", 
  "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.4"
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5"
}
```

The problem i face is getting an undefined value:

Above `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` is displaying the undefined on form submit but this is not what i am trying to implement.

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not find the recommended way to solve the the issue.

Comment: Please show how you access the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle enviroment variables inside React's you need to create an `.env` file at the root directory (besides `package.json` and everything else) and inside declare the variables you need.

Your `.env` file should be something like this (port is optional)

```
PORT=3000
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://yourexampleapi.com
```

Note that in order to see the changes you need to restart the development server.

Also, if you want to create new variables you need them to start with `REACT_APP_` (i.e `REACT_APP_VARIABLE_NAME`), otherwise React won't load those variables into your enviroment